# vector subscript out of range,Debug assertion failed

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm writing C++ code for a graphics program and in it I have to collect all coordinates to later parse them.I'm trying to use vectors for the same but the following error is returned:

> Debug Assertion failed
>   Program:....
>   File:....
>   Line 932
>   Expression:Vector subscript out of range

Here's part of my code:

```
std::vector<float> coordinates;
//random code
if(dnew >= 0)
{
   x = x + 1.0;

   glPointSize(1.5f);
   glColor3f(0.0,1.0,1.0);
   glBegin(GL_POINTS);
   glVertex2f(x, y);
   glEnd();
   dnew = dnew + a;
   if(t == 1)
   {
       coordinates.push_back (x);
   }
}

cout <<coordinates[1];
```

When I press retry it takes me to stdthrow.cpp and points to the following line:

```
_CRTIMP2_PURE void __CLRCALL_PURE_OR_CDECL _Debug_message(const wchar_t *message, const     wchar_t *file, unsigned int line)
{
    // report error and die
    if(::_CrtDbgReportW(_CRT_ASSERT, file, line, NULL, message)==1)
    {
        ::_CrtDbgBreak();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question? The error is pretty self-explanatory. (You've most likely hidden the code that contains the error with the `.....` in your `for` statement.)

Comment: for(.....) ? We need real loop for answer your question.

Comment: We don't need to see `for(.....)`... nooo.... We'll just guess...

Comment: You're using deprecated OpenGL code, FYI

Answer (score 2):

This error can be caused if `coordinates.size()<= i`, the exception is raised which gives you information that you tried to access element out of bounds of vector

Answer (score 1):

You only push one element into coordinates, so the only valid index is `0`. `coordinates[1]` is thus one past the end of the vector.

Further there are two conditions that could prevent the one `push_back` that is there at all from happening, so it might very well be, that your vector is empty. But you access the second element of the vector unconditionally.

Comment: No,I jus wrote down one instance in this question,the pushback is done several times in my code.

Comment: How do you suppose us to help you find the error, when you withhold the code that might trigger it? We can only judge what we can see.